# Is it a requirement that RPC providers (Infura, Ankr, Pocket, etc) collect a wallet's IP address?

Tags: network, rpc, privacy

If you do not run your own node and must interface with Ethereum network through an RPC like Infura, is it a requirement they collect your IP address in order to route the response back to you?

Of course they do not need to store it, but it is a requirement to collect it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address is needed so that responses are sent back to you.

Other explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233953/why-does-an-ip-header-need-to-have-source-address

---

---

What's probably important in privacy policies is explicitly stating that IP addresses are not retained, not stored, not collected. If a service is described as collecting IP packets, then that includes collecting IP addresses. But RPC providers probably don't describe themselves as collecting IP packets, and so describing themselves as collecting IP addresses sounds like they retrieve the IP addresses from the IP packets, discard the rest of the packet, and retain/store the IP addresses.